# Custom desktop PC won't boot or POST after power outage

Tags: boot, troubleshooting, desktop-computer, post

After a brief power outage the other night, [my custom desktop PC](https://pcpartpicker.com/b/MpHzK8) won't display anything even though it's plugged into a surge protector. The power turns on (the LEDs and fans activate, keyboard light activates) but it doesn't seem to boot or POST. When I power on the PC, the monitor will briefly wake up, then it says "No input" and goes back to sleep. There's a red light on the motherboard next to "VGA" text, so I thought my GPU was fried, but I tried plugging the monitor directly to the motherboard with no effect.

The PC was built in 2019 and has worked flawlessly for almost 4 years...until now.

**Things I've tried:**

- Plugged a different computer into the monitor. Monitor works fine.
- Held down the power button for 30 seconds with power cable unplugged.
- Reset the CMOS (removed CMOS battery and replaced).
- Tried different HDMI cables and displayport cables.
- Plugged the monitor directly into the motherboard with an HDMI
  cable.

Nothing seems to work.

Can anyone walk me through additional steps I can take to identify the problem?

Comment: What is the power supply doing in detail if you start the PC? Do you have access to a multimeter or PSU tester?

Comment: @mashuptwice I don't have access to any of those tools. Is there another way to check?

Comment: Well, the first question obviously was "What is the power supply doing in detail if you start the PC?". You might want to start by editing your question and including that information.

Comment: Do the fans start up?

Comment: @mashuptwice I don't understand the question. What "detail" are you asking for? If the PSU wasn't working, then I imagine the lights and fans wouldn't turn on. Do you want to know if the PSU is making an odd sound or some other indicator like that?

Comment: @harrymc yes, see second sentence. Fans and LED lights come on.

Comment: Are there any beeps during POST?